# Where in Navi does someone's arm shrivel up?

Tags: navi-prophets

I'm researching about how HaShem is constantly doing everything, and every second giving us all that we have. I think I remember that somewhere in Navi, there was a bad person that HaShem made his arm shrivel up, to show him that he doesn't have his own Koach, but he's dependent on HaShem, and better do Ratzon HaShem. If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: wow, 3 exact same answers all within 1 minute of each other!

Comment: @rikitikitembo - I know, right!?

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much to all of you for your fast and helpful reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be thinking of the intriguing story found in I Kings 13, in which King Jeroboam's arm miraculously shrivels up!

> (1) And behold a man of God came from Judah, at the command of the Lord, to Beth El, and Jeroboam was standing on the altar offering sacrifices.
>
> (2) And he called [in prophecy] about the altar at the command of the Lord, and he said: "Altar, altar, so said the Lord, "Behold a son will be born to the house of David, Josiah will be his name, and upon you he will slaughter all the priests of the high places who offer sacrifices on you, and human bones will they burn upon you."
>
> (3) And he gave a sign on that day saying: "This is the sign that the Lord has spoken." Behold the altar shall be split and the ashes that are upon it shall be spilled."
>
> (4) And it was, when the king heard the words of the man of God, which he proclaimed concerning the altar in Beth El, that Jeroboam stretched out his hand from over the altar saying: "Seize him!" And his hand that he had stretched out against him became stiff, and he could not draw his hand back to himself.

Additionally, Rashi comments on this:

> **And his hand… became stiff:** The Holy One, Blessed be He, avenged the honor of a righteous man more than [He avenged] His own honor. [When] he was standing and offering sacrifices to pagan deities, his hand did not become stiff, yet because of the disdain for the righteous man his hand became stiff.

(Via [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15897/jewish/Chapter-13.htm#showrashi=true))

Answer (score 3):

וַיְהִי֩ כִשְׁמֹ֨עַ הַמֶּ֜לֶךְ אֶת־דְּבַ֣ר אִישׁ־הָאֱלֹהִ֗ים אֲשֶׁ֨ר קָרָ֤א עַל־הַמִּזְבֵּ֙חַ֙ בְּבֵֽית־אֵ֔ל וַיִּשְׁלַ֨ח יָרָבְעָ֧ם אֶת־יָד֛וֹ מֵעַ֥ל הַמִּזְבֵּ֖חַ לֵאמֹ֣ר ׀ תִּפְשֻׂ֑הוּ וַתִּיבַ֤שׁ יָדוֹ֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר שָׁלַ֣ח עָלָ֔יו וְלֹ֥א יָכֹ֖ל לַהֲשִׁיבָ֥הּ אֵלָֽיו׃

When the king heard what the man of God had proclaimed against the altar in Bethel, Jeroboam stretched out his arm above the altar and cried, “Seize him!” But the arm that he stretched out against him became rigid, and he could not draw it back.

[Kings 1 13 4](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.13.4?with=all&lang=bi) Translation from Sefaria

Comment: This answer was posted first FWIW

Answer (score 1):

1 kings chapter 13 verse 4.

וַיְהִי֩ כִשְׁמֹ֨עַ הַמֶּ֜לֶךְ אֶת־דְּבַ֣ר אִישׁ־הָאֱלֹהִ֗ים אֲשֶׁ֨ר קָרָ֤א עַל־הַמִּזְבֵּ֙חַ֙ בְּבֵֽית־אֵ֔ל וַיִּשְׁלַ֨ח יָרָבְעָ֧ם אֶת־יָד֛וֹ מֵעַ֥ל הַמִּזְבֵּ֖חַ לֵאמֹ֣ר ׀ תִּפְשֻׂ֑הוּ **וַתִּיבַ֤שׁ** יָדוֹ֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר שָׁלַ֣ח עָלָ֔יו וְלֹ֥א יָכֹ֖ל לַהֲשִׁיבָ֥הּ אֵלָֽיו׃
When the king heard what the man of God had proclaimed against the altar in Bethel, Jeroboam stretched out his arm above the altar and cried, “Seize him!” But the arm that he stretched out against him became rigid, and he could not draw it back.

the bolded work וַתִּיבַ֤שׁ can be read to mean it dried up. Modern commentatories have described this as perhaps likened to gangrene